# Multithreading: simple program Segment fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, operating-system

I am trying to create a program which calculates prime numbers from 1 to 1000. I believe the code is having trouble either creating or joining the pthreads. I keep getting a core dump error. My main concern is in the second for loop where I am joining the pthreads. Is this the correct way to check if a thread has ended?

I am using gcc --std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pthread primes.c -o primes in the terminal.

```
    while (test_val <= FINAL){
        //loop to check if thread is finished
        for(int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++){
            if(tid[i] == 0){
                pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, testprime, NULL);

            }   
        }
        //wait for thread to end
        for(int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++){
            pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
```

This is the error:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: why are you overriding the thread ids with `1`: `tid[l] = 1;` ???

Comment: This is not an [mcve]...

Comment: you're also reading `test_val` outside critical section. and when `isprime` is set to false, you should break the loop.

Comment: also you should print something when the number is not prime. That's help debugging...

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
for(int l = 0; ti < MAX_THREADS; ti++){
    if(tid[l] == 0){
        pthread_create(&tid[l], NULL, testprime, NULL);
        tid[l] = 1;
    }   
}
```

First argument of `pthread_create` is an output thread handle. On the next line, you're setting this value to `1` (probably to mark it as used).

When performing `pthread_join` on those invalid handles, you invoke *undefined behaviour*.

Remove this assignment, thread handles aren't 0, so your code will work anyway.

Comment: Thank you that got rid of my error! But now my code doesn't print anything. Could this be because of the virtual machine I am running this on? Or is it something else in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to correct your for loop here. You don't need to assign a value in the array. When you call `pthread_create` it will store the thread id in every location of your thread array.

```
for(int ti = 0; ti < MAX_THREADS; ti++){
        if(tid[ti] == 0){
            pthread_create(&tid[ti], NULL, testprime, NULL);
            //tid[l] = 1;
        }
```